# Custom OpenSearch provider for Salesforce shows an error

Tags: search

I am trying to implement my own custom OpenSearch provider for Salesforce. I registered it as described in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.search_define_federated_search.htm&type=5). The validation and sync succeeded, but when I actually try to search for something, SFDC tells me: "*Hmm...something's not right. We can’t get your search results from <my_source_name>. Contact your Salesforce admin for help.*".

Obviously, something is wrong with the data returned by my OpenSearch source. But how can I get information on what exactly is wrong? Is there a way to get logs for these requests to external OpenSearch providers?